# symfony get repository function in controller 'none action' function

Tags: php, symfony

I have a controller where I have few functions which are not actions. I am calling that function with ajax, but I have a problem with repository. I am calling `AjaxControlsController` class and all ajax calls I am sending to that controller `indexAction` witch `action` param, and checking action in `switch` and from there I am calling the exact method of, for example , `SquadsController` `setFormation` function.
When I am trying to get repository in none action functions it returns me:

> Error: Call to a member function get() on null

How can I get and make work repository function in controller.

Controller

```
class SquadsController extends Controller {
    public function setFormation( $request )
        {
            $teamId = $request->request->get('teamid');
            $bIsSquadeEdit = false;
            $currentteamid = $request->request->get('currentteamid');

            if ( $currentteamid ) {
                $bIsSquadeEdit = true;
                $this->get('OulalaiFrame.repository.squad')->updateSquadFromation($this->aSlots,$currentteamid);
            }

            $this->formationList = $this->get('OulalaiFrame.repository.teams')->getFormation();
            $this->aFormationSlots = $this->get('OulalaiFrame.repository.teams')->assignFormationDetails($this->aSlots);
            $this->chackPlayersInFormation($this->aSlots,$teamId,$bIsSquadeEdit,true);

            return array(
                'leagueId'      => $this->leagueId, 
                'formationList' => $this->formationList,
                'playervalue'   => 45,
                'budget'        => $this->aBudget,
                'teamid'        => ( $this->iCurrentTeamId ) ? $this->iCurrentTeamId : null,
                'loadingteam'   => 0,
                'fieldFormation'=> $this->aFormationSlots,
                'formation'     => $this->aSlots,
                'playerslist'   => $this->aPlayers,
                'valid_team'    => $this->bIsValid,
                'budgetleft'    => $this->getBudgetLeft()
            );
        }
}
```

Repository

```
namespace OulalaiFrameBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
/**
 * TeamsRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class TeamsRepository 
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $em;


    /**
     * ConfigRepository constructor.
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * return array formations
     */
    public function getFormation()
    {
        $em = $this->em->getConnection()
            ->prepare(
                'SELECT * 
                 FROM `formation`'
            );
        $em->execute();
        $fromation = $em->fetchAll();
        return $fromation;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you call this method with ajax?

Comment: I am calling `AjaxControlsController` class and all ajax calls I am sending to that controller `indexAction` witch `action` param, and checking action in `switch` and from there I am calling the exact method of, for example , `SquadsController` `setFormation` function.

Comment: Is `$request` an instance of `Request` class?

Comment: @DrKey yes it is

Comment: Then you should just do `$request->get('teamid');`

Comment: I don't have a problem with $request, my problem is here `$this->get('OulalaiFrame.repository.teams')`

Comment: Your error says that you are calling function `get()` on `null` so I think `$request->request` is `null` rather than `$this`. Isn't it? Have you tried to dump variables?

Comment: Post the code of ajax action that calls this method and the code that creates instance of `SquadsController` if you do that manually. I guess that you didn't set container with `setContainer` method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Controller is instance of

> Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller